# php change characters indeliberately

Tags: php, http

I want to send a `GET` request to some url . I use `file_get_contents` function. 
But when I send a request to `http://www.somesite.com?key1=1&key2=2&key3=3`
it changes to `http://www.somesite.com?key1=1;key2=2;key3=3`.

In other words, I think this has some function that changes the `&` character to a `;` . 
how can I handle this?

Comment: kindly share your code

Comment: Use curl instead of file_get_contents

Answer (score 2):

i think curl extension is missing but the alternate way to do it can be

you can use this code in your server php script

```
$args = explode(";",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

$counter =0;

foreach($args as $arg)
{
    $temp_keys = explode("=",$arg);
    $keys[$temp_keys[0]] = $temp_keys[1];
}
```

and use the arguments according to logic

```
foreach($keys as $key=>$value)
{
  // somecode
}
```

print to see the result

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($keys);
print "</pre>";
```

and it gives output

```
Array
(
    [key1] => 1
    [key2] => 2
    [key3] => 3
)
```